# Selecionar dados JS

Tags: javascript

Estou com a seguinte dificuldade. Ao fazer a requisisao da API, vem todos os dados e eu gostaria de selecionar os dados que eu quero.

```
function fazerRequisicao() {
    ulr = 'https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/last/USD-BRL'

    var url = document.getElementById('url').value;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", url, false);

    xhttp.send();//A execução do script pára aqui até a requisição retornar do servidor

    document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;

    console.log(resposta)
}
```

Retorna

```
{"USDBRL":{"code":"USD","codein":"BRL","name":"Dólar Americano/Real Brasileiro","high":"5.1273","low":"5.0755","varBid":"0.0037","pctChange":"0.07","bid":"5.1125","ask":"5.115","timestamp":"1626469196","create_date":"2021-07-16 17:59:58"}}
```

Eu gostaria de saber como exibir apenas Dólar bid R$ 5.1125

Comment: Ja tentou usar innerhtml.substring(1, 50)no fim da instrução

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa *parsear* o resultado e com isso, acessar o campo desejado:

```js
     
        var url = 'https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/last/USD-BRL'
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xhttp.send();
    resposta = xhttp.responseText;
    r = JSON.parse(resposta); //JSON.parse transforma a string (JSON) 'resposta' em um objeto javascritp
    dolar_bid = r.USDBRL.bid //aqui, dentro o objeto criado, encontro a propriedade desejada
    document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = dolar_bid
```

```html
<div>R$ <span id="resposta"></span></div>
```